# What is the best way of object list casting

Tags: c#, list, casting, type-conversion

Is it possible to make my code more performance? I think there must be better way than "foreach".

My objects:

```
public class FirstObject{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalProp { get; set; }
}

public class SecondObject{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
List<SecondObject> secondObjectList = GetAllSecondObjects(); //This method returns tens of data

List<FirstObject> firstObjectList = new List<FirstObject>();

foreach(var item in secondObjectList){
    FirstObject obj = new FirstObject
    {
        Name = item.Name,
        DecimalProp = Convert.ToDecimal(item.StringProp)
    };
    firstObjectList.Add(obj);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it faster (on mulit-core systems) you could make it run in parallel:

```
secondObjectList.AsParallel().ForAll(s =>
    {
        FirstObject obj = new FirstObject
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            DecimalProp = Convert.ToDecimal(item.StringProp)
        };
        firstObjectList.Add(obj);
    });
```

Or combined using LINQ as Ehsan suggested:

```
var firstObjectList  = secondObjectList.AsParallel().Select(s => new FirstObject
                           {
                               Name = s.Name,
                               DecimalProp = Convert.ToDecimal(s.StringProp)
                           });
```

Other than that there is not much you can do, as the work needs to be done somehow and the overhead of a simple loops is rather small...

P.S.: Keep in mind that `AsParellel` can (and very likely will) change the order of the objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If your classes are very similar you can make inheritance and simplify the code like this:

```
    public class SecondObject : FirstObject
    {
        private string _stringProp;
        public string StringProp {
            get { return _stringProp; }
            set
            {
                _stringProp = value;
                DecimalProp = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

and then say

```
var secondObjectList = GetAllSecondObjects(); //This method returns tens of data

var firstObjectList = secondObjectList.Cast<FirstObject>().ToList();
```

I think that it has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want on liner you can do it using LINQ:

```
List<SecondObject> secondObjectList = GetAllSecondObjects(); //This method returns tens of data


var firstObjectList  = secondObjectList.Select(x=> new FirstObject
                           {
                              Name = x.Name,
                              DecimalProp = Convert.ToDecimal(x.StringProp)
                            }).ToList();
```